# mongoid nested hash and array is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a problem with MongoDB using MongoID. And i hope that someone can help me please. The objects in the DB has the following structure. (Collection Name is crashes). Sorry for the bad naming. I have to change that.

```
{
  id:String,
  title:String,
  new:String,
  crash:[
          {
            crash_reason:   {
              id:String,
              call:String
            },
            crashes:    [
              {
                id:String,
                app_id:String,
                info:String
              },
              {
                id:String,
                app_id:String,
                info:String
              },
              ... and many more
            ],
          },
          {
            crash_reason:   {
              id:String,
              call:String
            },
            crashes:    [
              {
                id:String,
                app_id:String,
                info:String
              },
              {
                id:String,
                app_id:String,
                info:String
              },
              ... and many more
            ],
          },
          ...
        ]
}
```

So when i put it into words. One object has some Main Values... and a crash array. The crash array contains all crashes. Each crash has again some main values stored in crash_reason as hash and after that there is another array with all crashes in it

Now i want to use MongoID (and Sinatra) but it seems that i am doing something wrong when i try to initialise it.

```
class Crashes
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :id, type: String
  field :title, type: String
  field :new, type: String
  embeds_many :crash
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :crash
end

class Crash
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :crashreason
  embeds_many :crashesm
  embedded_in :crashes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :crashesmulti, :crashreason
end

class Crashreason
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :id, type: String
  field :call, type: String
  embedded_in :crash
end

class Crashesmulti
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :id, type: String
  field :app_id, type: String
  field :info, type: String
  embedded_in :crash
end
```

then i want to make a simple query:

```
get '/mongo' do
  all_c = Crashes.all
  all_c.to_json
  @mongo = all_c
  haml:mongo
end
```

But i get the following Error. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Is the Nesting wrong? can i only nest different collections and have to use ARRAY and HASH type instead? If yes, how can i parametrize them ?

```
NoMethodError at /mongo
undefined method `relations' for file: embedded_in.rb location: determine_inverses
```

I also had a look to the documentation. But about Nested things, there is not much :-(.

Comment: Why do you have model `Crash` as well as `Crashes`? Something is really wrong here.

Comment: When the whole thing was not that big, I called the collection >crashes<. And since there are several objects that are then stored in this collection I have made the name in the majority. so crashes. When looking at an object in this collection, basic information can be seen in the top hierarchy. and then there is also an array deposited which is called crash. This array has more detailed informations... So the deeper you go in the structure, the more detailed it gets. 
But YES, as I said the naming all in all is a bad choice, I admit.

Or is there a problem wir the "s" at the end?

Comment: Ok, i think i have a wrong idea how mongoid is handling all that. I think nesting like i am trying to do it, is only possible with several collections. But i have just one with already nested hashes and arrays in it.